# How to increase Wildfly timeout on start/stop a group of servers?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-10, wildfly-cluster

I'm using Wildfly in domain mode and our bigger groups of servers (with big EARs deployed) always respond our start/stop with

> Request timeout

after few seconds, even when the command start/stop occurring with success in the servers.

With our smallest applications (WARs), the start/stop return successful messages:

> Server Group STARTED succeeded

I'm trying to find some configuration that I can increase this waiting time start/stop time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time-out span is hard-coded in the current implementation of the console. It stops polling the server status after about 7.5 seconds.It's not harmful from a server instance's point of view.